# Prevent On.Time from running multiple times

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following macro assigned to a button:

```
Sub refresh()

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    Call repeat

End Sub

Sub repeat()

    TimeToRun = Now + TimeValue("00:05:00")
    Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "refresh"

End Sub
```

If the button is clicked more than once, I get multiple instances of this macro running.

Is there a way to cancel any macros running prior to commencing the Sub refresh()?

Comment: An easy way would be to prevent the multiple instances of `repeat()`

Comment: From the VBA refernce, you have a parameter for such action. `Set Schedule to false to clear a procedure previously set with the same Procedure and EarliestTime values.'  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196165.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Dim TimeToRun

Sub refresh()

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    Call repeat

End Sub

Sub repeat()

    If TimeToRun > 0 Then
         'cancel previous...
         Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "refresh", False
    End If

    TimeToRun = Now + TimeValue("00:05:00")
    Application.OnTime TimeToRun, "refresh"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, that worked perfectly. Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add the cancellation code in repeat but it did not work. I have added another sub that should run when the button is clicked. Range("G1") is a cell i use to store the time value.

```
Sub refresh()

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Call repeat

End Sub


Sub repeat()

    TimeToRun = Now + TimeValue("00:00:10")

    'stoer the TimeToRun
    Range("G1") = TimeToRun

    'schedule the next refresh
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=TimeToRun, Procedure:="refresh", Schedule:=True

End Sub


Sub subForClick()

    If Not (IsEmpty(Range("G1"))) Then
        Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=Range("G1").Value, Procedure:="refresh", Schedule:=False
    End If

    Call refresh
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Nightcrawler23, thank you so much for your help, I didn't attempt this method as the answer provided above has solved my issue. Thanks for providing the link to the Application.OnTime method explanation - it's great info!

Answer (score 0):

Late for the party, but I create a function to check the time and let the user run the code again after some time.

```
Private Function timeCheck() As Boolean

    If VBA.Now() > TimeControl.Range("A1").Value + VBA.TimeValue("00:05:00") Then
        timeCheck = True
    Else
        timeCheck = False
    End If

End Function
```

Where TimeControl is the name of the sheet that holds the time value on range A1.

So you just need to use this function as below:

```
If timeCheck = True Then
   TimeControl.Range("A1").Value = VBA.Now()
   do something
else
   do something else
end if
```